# initialValues does not get update when updating the form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a form called `Client` which has a single form which handles both `add` and `edit`. Add is working but when editing the form(form
is populated with initialValues if it's and edit form), the initialValues does not get update. I mean, if I go to client A form and update the
field called `client_name` from 'abc' to 'xyz' then the client_name will be saved as 'xyz' in server but the initialValues does not get update 
so if i again go to same form without refreshing the page and save the form without changing anything then `client_name` is saved with previous
value i. 'abc' because initialValues is not updated when updating the field.

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm, initialize } from 'redux-form';


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => ({
  addClient: clientData => dispatch(addClient(clientData)),
  editClient: clientData => dispatch(editClient(clientData)),
  loadClient: () => dispatch(loadClient(props.match.params.company)),
  resetClient: () => dispatch(resetClient()),
});

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  initialValues: selectClient(),
});


class Client extends Component<propsCheck> {
  state = {
    client: initialState,
    isLoading: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.match.params.company) {
      this.props.loadClient();
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.match.params.company) {
      this.props.loadClient();
    } else {
      this.props.resetClient();
    }
  }

  handleChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    this.setState({ client: { ...this.state.client, [name]: value } });
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { client } = this.state;
    const { initialValues, addClient: add, editClient: edit } = this.props;
    if (isEmpty(initialValues)) {
      add(client);
    } else {
      const updatedClient = updatedValue(initialValues, client, 'id');
      edit(updatedClient);
    }
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
  };

  render() {
    const { invalid, submitting, initialValues } = this.props;
    return (
          <ClientForm
            loading={this.state.isLoading}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            disabled={invalid || submitting}
            type={initialValues && initialValues.id ? 'Edit' : 'Add'}
            reset={this.props.reset}
            history={this.props.history}
          />
    );
  }
}


const withReduxForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'clientForm',
  fields: requiredFields,
  validate,
  enableReinitialize: true,
})(Client);

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(withReduxForm);
```

Comment: Your initial values are being populated from redux state (selectClient in mapStateToProps) right? So, when you update/edit the client_name, are you changing the data in redux??

Comment: yes initialValues is populated from redux state. Thanks a lot i forgot the EDIT_CLIENT in reducer.

Comment: I can move the comment to answers, would you mind marking it as the answer??

Comment: yes sure. I should respect your time, consideration and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial values are being populated from redux state (selectClient in mapStateToProps) right? So, when you update/edit the client_name, are you changing the data in redux??